# Update of Ubuntu Server 16.04 broke my OwnCloud 9 server?

Tags: updates, apache2, owncloud-server

I'm running a small server for domestic use with Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and Owncloud. I keep my server up to date with `apt-get update/upgrade`.
Yesterday evening 26 July 2016 I did an update resulting in approx. 35 packages being updated.
Next: My OC client couldn't connect to my server anymore.
The webpage of OC looks alright but when I try to login, there's no response. 
Just Username, Password and no message about what so ever.
Couldn't find anything in the server logs. I tried to connect via OCC (an owncloud commandline tool), that worked. So OC is running all right.

Result: After updating Ubuntu server 16.04. No access to OwnCloud is possible with the oc-client and/or oc webinterface.

Checked the OC logging. Nothing. Clean.
Checked the Apache logging. (`File /var/log/apache2/error.log`) again. Nothing.

Any suggestions?

Thanx.

Hans.

Answer (score 0):

go into your /var/www/owncloud folder, or wherever you installed your owncloud instance. look for a directory called "config" then a file called config.php
edit the line in the file that reads maintenance => true and make it maintenance => false. To edit you might have to chown to www-data.

Terminal:
1.cd /var/www/owncloud/config/
2.sudo nano config.php
3.change line to 'maintenance =>false'
4.save the file, reboot the system 
5.enter owncloud through your browser, you might have to perform an update. 
6. when its done you should be ok

owncloud documentation on maintenance mode:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/admin_manual/maintenance/enable_maintenance.html